# Group data by team

Tags: sql

I have a status that is used to show when work is passed from one team to another. I need to be able to run a query to show the work orders that were reassigned and the from and to teams from the auditing a_workorder table.

```
   status         persongroup     wonum     eaudittimestamp
1. REASSIGN       TEAM4           324153    30/07/2014 22:15
2. REASSIGN       CARP            324153    30/07/2014 22:15
3. REASSIGN       TEAM1           324145    30/07/2014 22:34
4. REASSIGN       FOODBEV         324145    30/07/2014 22:34
```

If query is run for all wonum with include persongroup of CARP, then line 1 and 2 should be returned as TEAM4 reassigned the work order number 324153 to CARP.

Comment: why not returning line2 instead of 3 together with 4? dont quite understand

Comment: Can you show literall what you expect the output to be?  Also, how do you know that TEAM4 was reassigned to CARP and not the other way around?  Does the initial value (1, 2, 3, 4) have a field, or did you just number that?

Comment: It's an impossible task unless you have any data that can be used to determine *from* and *to* teams?

Comment: The e-audit timestamp goes down to the millisecond so I am able to see who passed the job to whom. I numbered these 1 through 4. If looking for jobs re-assigned to carp, I want lines 1 & 2 to return, the timestamp is then used to determine who passed to whom and lines 3 & 4 would not return.

Comment: Any line that contains carp needs to also return any other lines with the same wonum that corresponds to carp, in this case line 1

Comment: What RDBMS?  This is really trivial for any that support `LAG(...)`/`LEAD(...)` (and only slightly more difficult if you have `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is sort of an inelegant solution (it always gives me pause when I use `select distinct`), but it may give you a foundation for what you need:

```
with ranks as (
  select
    persongroup, wonum, eaudittimestamp,
    min (eaudittimestamp) over (partition by wonum) as min_time,
    max (eaudittimestamp) over (partition by wonum) as max_time
  from a_workorder
), wos as (
  select distinct wonum
  from a_workorder
)
select
  wos.wonum, r1.persongroup as first_group,
  r2.persongroup as last_group
from
  wos
  join ranks r1 on
    wos.wonum = r1.wonum and
    r1.eaudittimestamp = r1.min_time
  join ranks r2 on
    wos.wonum = r2.wonum and
    r2.eaudittimestamp = r2.max_time
```

Results from your sample data:

```
wonum   first_group   last_group
-----   -----------   ----------
324153  'TEAM4'       'CARP'
324145  'TEAM1'       'FOODBEV'
```